# Android Application History

Tags: android

Is there a way to check what applications a user used in the last 24 hours? In other words, is there an 'application history log' of some kind which is accessible through programming?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [`RecentTaskInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo.html). The docs:

> Information you can retrieve about tasks that the user has most
>   recently started or visited.